# Speed difference between bracket notation and dot notation for accessing columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance

Let's have a small dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame({'CID': [1,2,3,4,12345, 6]})`

When I search for membership the speed is vastly different based on whether I ask to search in `df.CID` or in `df['CID']`.

```
In[25]:%timeit 12345 in df.CID
Out[25]:89.8 µs ± 254 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In[26]:%timeit 12345 in df['CID']
Out[26]:42.3 µs ± 334 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In[27]:type( df.CID)
Out[27]: pandas.core.series.Series

In[28]:type( df['CID'])
Out[28]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Why is that?

Comment: Not a full answer but; _always_ use bracket indexing when referring to columns in pandas. The dot shortcut works, but it's bad practice. One reason, and likely one of the reasons it takes longer, is that in python, `object.thing` is generally used for attributes of the object. In this case, a dataframe has attributes like `.shape, .columns, .name` (this last one is another good reason, with brackets you can have a column called `['name']`) so there's overhead with trying to access a column as an attribute rather than explicitly as a column

Comment: +/- margins very large tho — certain the effect is real/general?

Comment: I think you want to be using df['CID'] in most cases as there are some nuances to accessing a column through a DataFrame attribute. Also I wanted to added that I think you want to search for 12345 in df['CID'].values, to check if that number is in the series. Otherwise it will check if that number is in the index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`df['CID']` delegates to [`NDFrame.__getitem__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L3115-L3116) and it is more obvious you are performing an indexing operation.

On the other hand, `df.CID` delegates to [`NDFrame.__getattr__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L5117-L5131), which has to do some additional heavy lifting, mainly to determine whether 'CID' is an attribute, a function, or a column you're calling using the attribute access (a convenience, but not recommended for production code).

---

Now, why is it not recommended? Consider,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})
df.A

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

There are no issues referring to column "A" as `df.A`, because it does not conflict with any attribute or function namings in pandas. However, consider the [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) function (just as an example).

```
df.pop
# <bound method NDFrame.pop of ...>
```

`df.pop` is a bound method of `df`. Now, I'd like to create a column called "pop" for various reasons.

```
df['pop'] = [4, 5, 6]
df
   A  pop
0  1    4
1  2    5
2  3    6
```

Great, but,

```
df.pop
# <bound method NDFrame.pop of ...>
```

I cannot use the attribute notation to access this column. However...

```
df['pop']

0    4
1    5
2    6
Name: pop, dtype: int64
```

Bracket notation still works. That's why this is better.

Comment: So in conclusion don't set the column names that live in df function space.

Comment: @prosti No, sometimes that cannot be avoided. The real conclusion here is to use `df['col']` instead of `df.col` unless you're certain 'col' is not an attribute or function name.

Comment: This is so eloquently put for something I always try to explain when I see people using the `df.col` accessing. Thanks for this!