# Accessing Dataframe columns using bracket vs dot notation in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

Which is the recommended way to access Dataframe columns in Julia: Using `df[:col]` or `df.col`? For example, in Pandas Dataframe, the recommended way is using the bracket notation for performance as well as other reasons as discussed here: [Speed difference between bracket notation and dot notation for accessing columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240925/speed-difference-between-bracket-notation-and-dot-notation-for-accessing-columns).

So, is there a similar recommendation for using bracket notation over the dot notation for Dataframes in Julia, either for performance or otherwise? Or are both equally good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equally good, and normally `df.col` is used. There are two cases when you need to use the other style:

- when column name is not a valid identifier, e.g. `df[Symbol("Some column name with spaces")]`
- soon broadcasting for data frames will be implemented and then if `col` does not exist in `df` the syntax `df.col .= 1` will not work while `df[:col] .= 1` will create a new column.

Note that `df.col` notation is handy as if you write `df.` and press `<tab>` in REPL or Jupyter Notebook you will get a list of column names.

Comment: For getting the list of column names in REPL, do I need to write df. and press enter or some other key? Because on pressing enter it says "ERROR: syntax: incomplete: premature end of input"

Comment: For some reason StackOverflow did not show `<tab>`. I have fixed this.