# Pandas: inconsistent iteration problems

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
d = {"col1":[1,2], "col2":[3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

print(type(df.col1))
print(type(df["col1"]))

for index, col1 in df.col1.items():
    pass

for index, col1 in df["col1"]:
    pass
```

This outputs:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a346dc42f5cd> in <module>
      9     pass
     10 
---> 11 for index, col1 in df["col1"]:
     12     pass

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

But why can only 1 be iterated? Both object types are the same as indicated by the print-outs.

Comment: they are not the same, df.col1.items creates a generator object, do `print(type(df.col1.items())`

Comment: Okay sorry, so I tried `df["col1"].items` and it still doesn't work tho

Comment: `items` is a function, it looks like you forgot to call it.

Comment: @cs95 Oh thanks! It works now! So `df.col1` and `df["col1"]` functions exactly the same if the column name has no spaces?

Comment: Yes they are equivalent, with some important differences. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240925/speed-difference-between-bracket-notation-and-dot-notation-for-accessing-columns/56241496#56241496), in general we recommend you use `df['col1']` in general because it is safer and works for any column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have different data underneath, here's a look at the items list ( the .items includes the rows):

```
In [177]: list(df.col1.items())                                                                                                                                                                
Out[177]: [(0, 1), (1, 2)]

In [178]: list(df["col1"])                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[178]: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

The items() method returns iterable of tuples containing the (index, value) pairs from the Series
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html

Series inherits its **iter**() from IndexOpsMixin, which returns an iterator over the values of the series. ( https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/base.py ). Hence, it does not yield a tuple of the index and value, but only the value.