# How to lookup different dataframes and return the values?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, anaconda

Im trying to lookup the index in two different datframes and return the values.

For example, in df1 i would like to lookup in df2 and return the same index and values.

DF1 [image]

DF2 [image]

I would like my result to be like this.

RESULTS [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
new_df = df2[df2.ID == [list(df1.ID)]]
```

Comment: dot notation is not best practice for pandas https://stackoverflow.com/a/56241496/11280068

Comment: Too much pyspark for me where I use '.' rather than col('...'), probably a bad habit!

Comment: dont work if its not the same length

Comment: .isin() should work (as answered below by Nicholas)

Answer (score 1):

Get the IDs from df2 where the ID is in df1

```
filtered_df = df2[(df2['ID'].isin(df1['ID']))]
```

Comment: work but what if i df1 98,95,88,85,81,86,100. how do i return the values in that order. Some one the numbers or not in order but i would like to keep in the order of df1

Comment: there isn't an easy way to do custom sorting in pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838405/custom-sorting-in-pandas-dataframe